# Ruby Could not find gem, but gem exist

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-16.04, fluentd

I'm trying to execute an unit test in a fluentD project by inserting in the console:

```
bundle exec rake test test/plugin/test_out_foo.rb
```

But it returns the following:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.40)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Could not find gem 'parallel_tests (~> 0.15.3)' in any of the gem sources 
listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm not worried with the "Not a git repository" because for what I read it doesn't influence the result of this test. Then if I try to enter 'bundle install' as suggested it returns:

```
Installing cool.io 1.5.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-
0.12.40/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/cool.io-1.5.1/ext/cool.io
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170928-2385-ss02z5.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
...
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for port.h... no
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which 
can be found here:

/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-
0.12.40/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/cool.io-
1.5.1/mkmf.log

...

Make sure that `gem install cool.io -v '1.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.
An error occurred while installing cool.io (1.5.1), and Bundler cannot 
continue.
```

In the mkmf.log, the first (but not only) error is:

```
conftest.c:13:57: error: ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’ undeclared (first use 
in this function)
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)
()))rb_thread_blocking_region; return !p; }
```

If I enter 'gem list' in the console it shows parallel_tests (2.7.1) and cool.io (1.5.1), so I don't understand why these errors happen.

I also have seen this link https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1314. Which compiling Ruby with dynamic libraby instead of static libraby could solve the problem. But, since I installed Ruby, I should not need to compile it, right?

The OS is an Ubuntu 16.04, Ruby version is 2.3.1 and FluentD version is 0.12.40.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Right, erm, where to begin?.... First off, the title of your question is clearly wrong; the `parallel_tests (~> 0.15.3)` gem **doesn't**  exist. You only have `v2.7.1` installed. Presumably, the correct version is listed further down in the `Gemfile.lock`, but this installation is never being attempted since you hit another failure first.

Comment: As for the `cool.io` gem, I'm confused what's happening here. You say it's installed, yet `bundle install` still tries (and fails) to install it. My first suggestion would be to `gem uninstall cool.io`, then re-run `bundle install` and see what happens.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/tarcieri/cool.io/issues/5) in the cool.io repo, but apparently this only applies to `jruby`, not `mri`. I also found this [possible fix](https://gist.github.com/bhardin/962761029555b68f95fa): `gem install cool.io -v -- with-cflags="-std=c99"`

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for the response. I already did `gem uninstall cool.io` and re-run `bundle install`, but the same error happen again. Using `gem install cool.io -v -- with-cflags="-std=c99"` it returns the same error but with some extra warnings. The first one is `#warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"` and at the end it says `Makefile:239: recipe for target 'libev.o' failed
make: *** [libev.o] Error 1`.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest, sorry... Possibly you need to update your version of `gcc`? Anyway, I'd raise this as an issue on the `cool.io` repo, since this seems to be the whole source of your problem.